# Paste values instead of formulas

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I want to copy certain values in cells from one tab into another.

```vb
    Sheets("Equities").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ZSM").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Bonds").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ZSM").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I want to modify the code to also copy the values (I only want the value the formula gives back) from formulas (e.g. "= J5*K24").

I modified the code the following way:

```vb
    Sheets("Equities").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ZSM").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial               ###here
    Sheets("Bonds").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ZSM").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial                  ##here
```

I read a bit about the PasteSpecial method but could not apply it.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but please please please read [How to avoid Select in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?s=1|259.1623).

Comment: For example, you can use `Sheets("Equities").Range("B5").Copy //
Sheets("ZSM").Range("B5").PasteSpecial xlValues` or even quicker the one-line `Sheets("ZSM").Range("B5").value=Sheets("Equities").Range("B5").value`.

Comment: `xlPasteValues` Here's the list of available options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype

Comment: Now I edited my post. I hope that clarifies the problem. Thank you :)

Comment: SJR's initial comment cannot be overstated. Please avoid the use of `Select` in VBA. It can lead to weird behaviour that is not easy to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget the PasteSpecial xlValues and perform a direct value transfer hereby bypassing the clipboard altogether.

```
dim zsm as worksheet

set zsm = workSheets("ZSM")

with workSheets("Equities")
    with .Range(.range(.cells(5, "B"), .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup)), _
                .range(.cells(5, "B"), .cells(5, .columns.count).end(xltoleft)))
        zsm.cells(5, "B").resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .value
    end with
end with

with workSheets("Bonds")
    with .Range(.range(.cells(5, "B"), .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup)), _
                .range(.cells(5, "B"), .cells(5, .columns.count).end(xltoleft)))
        zsm.cells(zsm.rows.count, "B").end(xlup).offset(1, 1).resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .value
    end with
end with
```

Are you sure that last offset should be offset(1, 1) and not offset(1, 0)?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing about the (1,1) offset... Seems kind of strange.

Comment: yeah it is strange because I did not show you my whole code. I am sorry about that.

Comment: Now I edited the question. I hope that helps. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Now you're just overwriting almost all the data in ZSM you got from Equities with the values from Bonds. In addition, you've rendered this response completely invalid.

Comment: Yeah thats what this response does. I wanted to show you why I have to use offset(1,1). As I said, I am really knew to this and do not know how I have to behave in stackoverflow. I apologize for the inconveniences. Hope that someone can hepl

Comment: @dwirony I now edited the post back to the normal question. Thank you for your help. For my problem I posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401097/paste-values-instead-of-formulas-with-pastespecial-vbanewbie    I would really appreciate your support. Thank you!